# Java - Override a foreign method

Tags: java, overriding

I'm trying to make a spcial add-ons for my application. I need to override some methods of a class without editing the class file.

Here is a scheme:

```
class A
{
    public void method1()
    {
        // Do something here
    }

    public int method2()
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Now from my class B, I want to override the method1 func from the class A, and force the A class to use my new method.

```
class B
{
    public void method1()
    {
        Do something
    }
}
```

I want to update my class A code without editing the A class. Is that possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure I understand.  You're saying you now want `A a = new A(); a.method1()` to call `B.method1`?

Comment: You can't change the behavior that is already defined in class `A`, the best you can do is extend from class `A` and change the behavior in class `B`. Then call all of your methods on class `B` objects.

Comment: In Java you cannot "replace" the original class, akin to what is possible in Objective C -- you need to override and ensure others are using the new class.

Comment: "I want to update my class A code without editing the A class" hmm isn't that a contradiction?

Comment: Well, I don't want to extend something. I want to say in B something like `Hey, when class A will try to start the method method1(), ask it to use mine and when class C will try to start the method ..., use mine`

Comment: @Alvin: in some languages, that would actually be possible.

Comment: Is there a way to catch when a method is launched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like proxy can solve your problem. Take a look at [cglib](http://cglib.sourceforge.net/)

```
Enhancer e = new Enhancer();
e.setSuperclass(A.class);
e.setCallback(new MyCallback());
A proxied = e.create();
```

And here is sample impl of MyCallback class...

```
class MyCallback implements MethodInterceptor{
       public Object intercept(Object obj,
                                      Method method,
                                      Object[] args,
                                      MethodProxy proxy){
            Object stuffToReturn = null;
            if ("method1".equals(method.getName()) {
                 //Class B's method1 impl 
            } else {
                 //call the original method in class A
                 stuffToReturn  = method.invoke(proxy, args);
            }

            return stuffToReturn;   
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, this won't affect the behaviour of the objects instantiated by simple `new A`.

Comment: Well, the poster only asked not to modify class A, so it sounded like he can change new A() to e.create()? If the poster cannot even change new A() statements then probably have to modify the byte code of class A dynamically...

Comment: This is long way to doing this. you can do this by extending `B` result is same

Comment: @Nirmal, no it's not the long way. What if class A is final? What if method A is final? The poster specifically says he doesn't want to extend anything.

Answer (score 4):

use `class B extends A` and ovverride method that you want to change. how ever you have to use  instance of class `B` not `A`. like

```
class B extends A
{
    public void method1(){
      Do something
    }
}
A a = new B();
a.method1();
```

Comment: again, this is changing the behavior of `B`, and not `A`'s. This is a workaround which is not always possible. `new A().method1()` will have the same behavior as it had before. However - at least this answer explicitly mentions that it affects only `B`.

Answer (score 1):

Not if you create your objects using `A` constructor.
You could have `B` extend `A`, but you will have to instantiate objects as `new B()` (even if you can *declare* them as `A`, as in `A obj = new B()`).

Answer (score 1):

No, in languages like Java this is not possible directly. `new A` will always create at runtime an instance of `A`, not of a derived `B`.

If it's possible (that is, if you control all the code which instantiates `A`), you can use some clumsy workarounds introducing a kind of indirection. For example, you can have a configurable factory producing `A`s (which will on demand switch to producing `B`s under the cover) -- this seems to be the Java way. (You'll need all the code construct `A`s not directly, but through the factory.)

If I am not mistaken, the feature you are looking for is available in Objective C out of the box -- but not in Java.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a way to catch an event when a method is launched?

Comment: No way of which I am aware of, sorry :(

Comment: +1. Also, side note/question: I am not a C# expert, but I know you can add fields on the fly there using reflection - maybe it can be done as well [in C#]? [will be glad if someone knows the answer for it]. However - in java, it cannot be achieved with reflection, and AFAIK cannot be achieved at all.

Comment: @amit: wow, I didn't know about this C# feature! Could you please share some more information about it? (Or is this about `ExpandoObject`?)

Comment: @Vlad: As I said, I am not a C# expert, I just remember reading it about a year ago [reliable source]... I am not the place to address these questions :)

Comment: @amit: one possible way could be listening to [`AppDomain.AssemblyResolve`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx) event and somehow mangling the classes on load -- but my knowledge of C# internals is not so advanced.

Answer (score 0):

By inheritance, yes. Simply change the class B definition : `class B extends A`

Comment: No, `new A().method1()` will still invoke the original one. You modified `class B` and not `class A`'s behavior as requested

Comment: @amit If you read the post, the OP says he does _not_ want to modify class A.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: He wants to modify `A`'s *behavior* without modifying it, and not the behavior of `B`.

Comment: @amit Without editing the source file, there is no way to change the existing behaivor. Inheritance gives him a workaround.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: Then the answer should be "no, but..." and not "yes"

Comment: @amit reading your answer confuse me. You want to override method1 but keeping a reference to the class A (new A() ). Why not working with class B reference (new B() ). If you can't, Snicolas's answer can resolve your problem.

Comment: @EricR.: I am not the OP, but "use a B instead of A" is a workaround, which is not always can be applied. Also, the answer is definetly not "yes" when you take this approach, since this approach does not fulfill the requirement - which is change the behavior of `A`. It only changes the behavior of `B`.

Answer (score 0):

This has no sense. Overriding means precisely to re-define a method that is inherited from a super class. So here are some solutions :

- B must extend A and then you can override one of the methods of A. Give it the same signature as in A, use the @Override annotation to be sure.
- A has some dependency that is injected : method1 and method2 use some tierce object (C) to get the job done and the dependency is injected in A. Then B can use a A with custom C object that suits its needs. Most of code of A won't change that way.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this would be to use some sort of [factory instance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) to create objects of type A instead of invoking the A() constructor directly in your code. Your add-on would then need to provide and register its own implementation of this factory which would create instances of class B. This only works if the add-on gets loaded and initialized before any instances of A were created.

Another approach would be to implement your own ClassLoader and use this to modify the bytecode of class A at loading time. You could search for tools for [aspect oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) to implement this. This is only possible if you have control over the class loading process of class A.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that, it's impossible to modify the behavior of a class without actually modifying the class, however, there is a workaround:

1. B should be inherited from A. This is absolutely needed. A won't change, but its children classes might change in behavior
2. Overwrite method1() and method2()
3. Suppose you have an a object of the A class. If you convert it to B, its behavior will be your new, custom behavior.